# render_template with ajax in flask

Tags: ajax, flask

In `app.py` I have:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index_as_post():
    slider_value=0

    if request.method == "POST":
        slider_value = request.form.get('proba_thresholds', 0, type=int)


    ''' here plot the data'''
    ...
    graphJSON = json.dumps(data, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    return render_template('index.html', graphJSON=graphJSON)
```

and `templates/index.html` has

```
...
<form method="POST" action="\" id="form">

        <div class="slidecontainer">
          <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="proba_thresholds" id="slide" class="slider" value="50"/>
          <p>Value: <span id="slider_value"></span></p>

            <script>
            var slider = document.getElementById("slide");
            var output = document.getElementById("slider_value");
            output.innerHTML = slider.value;

            slider.oninput = function() {
              output.innerHTML = this.value;
              $.ajax({ url: '/', 
                      data: $(form).serialize(), 
                      type:'POST'
              });
            }
            </script>

        </div>
</form>

<div id="barPlot" class="chart">
</div>
```

`proba_thresholds` gets updated, HOWEVER, render_template does not update the html. **WHY** and **HOW do I solve it?**

Thank you!

Comment: Can someone explain why the negative vote? Is the question difficult to understand? If not, why not providing me with the answer instead (even in addition!) of voting down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax was doing nothing upon success or failure.

```
slider.oninput = function() {
                  output.innerHTML = this.value;
                  $.ajax({ 
                    url: '/', //'/test', 
                    data: $(form).serialize(), 
                    type:'POST', 
                  })

                  .done(function(data) {
                    var graphs = JSON.parse(data);
                    Plotly.react('barPlot', graphs, {});
                    console.log("funciona")})

                  .fail(function(){console.log("no funciona")});
                }
```

Will plot the data when function is executed successfully. ALSO, graphs expect json data and not a rendered html, so in app.py:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index_as_post():
    slider_value = request.form.get('proba_thresholds', 0, type=int)

    data = plotit(slider_value)
    graphJSON = json.dumps(data, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    return graphJSON #render_template('index.html', graphJSON=graphJSON)
```

I couldn't find any non-deep explanation and I hope that someone will correct me here, ajax will modify the DOM but is not expecting a rendered html, rather json data. There is no routing.